# Using 'Expect' to check partial text content

Tags: selenium, protractor

I want to use 'Expect' to verify presence of a certain text string in an element.

The element I'm looking at will contain the following text:

"Your booking reference is: DBM038763."

I want to confirm that "DBM" appears in the text

```
var conf1 = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText();
    expect(conf1.textToBePresentInElement("DBM"));
```

This will return:

```
    - Failed: conf1.textToBePresentInElement is not a function
```

I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious!
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the value present in `conf1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textToBePresentInElement` is an [expectedCondition](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.textToBePresentInElement) but you are attempting to call it as a method on `conf1` which is a promise eventually returning a string via `getText()`. You need to change you syntax slightly to use expected conditions as below:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var conf1 = element(by.xpath(".//*[@id='root']/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/h4")).getText();
expect(EC.textToBePresentInElement(conf1, "DBM")).toBe(true); //added .toBe(true)
```

Default example provided in link above

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
// Waits for the element with id 'abc' to contain the text 'foo'.
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement($('#abc'), 'foo'), 5000);
```

Comment: My answer should actually read like `expect(EC.textToBePresentInElement(conf1, "DBM")).toBe(true)`. I forgot to append `.toBe(true)` originally

Answer (score 1):

If value is present in `conf1` then you can use the below.

```
 expect(conf1).toContain("DBM")
```